# windows cannot file http port in sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have Downloaded Oracle 11g and after installation i am having this problem.
Windows Cannot find path 'http://127.0.0.1:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950'. Make Sure you typed the name correctly, and then try agian.

[image]

Comment: By default it's 8080. Try http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950

Comment: So What should i do now for running my Oralce.